# How define a flag based on transaction date in the last month on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table like this

| Customer_ID | Category | Subcategory1 | Subcategory2 | Transaction_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Vehicle | Car | Sedan | 23/05/2023 |
| 1 | Vehicle | Car | Sedan | 20/06/2023 |
| 1 | Vehicle | Car | Sedan | 23/01/2023 |
| 2 | Vehicle | Car | SUV | 23/01/2023 |
| 3 | Vehicle | Car | MPV | 23/04/2023 |
| 3 | Vehicle | Car | Wagon | 23/02/2023 |
| 2 | Vehicle | Car | Jeep | 23/04/2023 |
| 4 | Vehicle | Car | Sedan | 23/02/2023 |

I want to set a flag based on the transaction date. If within 30 days from the transaction date on the same customer buy with the same Category + Sub-Category 1 + Sub-Category 2 then the flag will be N. and the others will be Y.

here's the expected result

| Customer_ID | Category | Subcategory1 | Subcategory2 | Transaction_date | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Vehicle | Car | Sedan | 23/05/2023 | Y |
| 1 | Vehicle | Car | Sedan | 20/06/2023 | N |
| 1 | Vehicle | Car | Sedan | 23/01/2023 | Y |
| 2 | Vehicle | Car | SUV | 23/01/2023 | Y |
| 3 | Vehicle | Car | MPV | 23/04/2023 | Y |
| 3 | Vehicle | Car | Wagon | 23/02/2023 | Y |
| 2 | Vehicle | Car | Jeep | 23/04/2023 | Y |
| 4 | Vehicle | Car | Sedan | 23/02/2023 | Y |

How can I perform with the query?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `lead` to get the next transaction date, and then use a case expression to calculate the flag:

```sql
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN 
         DATEDIFF(day, 
                  transaction_date,
                  LEAD(transaction_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id,
                                                            category,
                                                            subcategory1,
                                                            subcategory2
                                               ORDER BY transaction_date))                          
          < 30
       THEN 'N' 
       ELSE 'Y'
       END
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: @SelVazi - thanks for the edit. Stupid typo on my side :-(

Comment: Its happens, Also when no next transaction date exists it get wrong flag, you need to initialize the transaction date https://dbfiddle.uk/8N5EGTt3

Comment: @SelVazi good point - you need to explicitly check for `null`s here. See my edited answer.

Comment: You still have to fix it again :), `CASE WHEN  next_transaction_date IS NULL OR
                 DATEDIFF(DAY, transaction_date, next_transaction_date) > 30` https://dbfiddle.uk/-evihcG4

Comment: @SelVazi mea culpa, needed to read the requirements more carefully. But now that I have, this entire mess with checking `null`s seems redundant. Simply flipping the condition would do the trick.

Comment: @mureinik thanks for help. i tried it but i seems still wrong

Comment: @Paktelo can you elaborate?

Comment: @mureinik the result is very random. some datas got right flag but many others still got wrong values as expected.  for example if the conditions like customer_id=1 above, all flag is Y.